# Limit the size of characters to input

Tags: c++

Hello I need help in my C++ program so I just need user to input their first name and if it exceeds in 25 characters there will be some error message. But I have this code and if I input 26 characters it doesn't give error. tried both string.size() and string.length();

```
// I already included string
// first_name is string
if (first_name.size() <= 25) {
        cin >> first_name;
    }
    else {
        cout << "You must only put 25 characters";
        system("cls");
    }
```

Comment: The problem with the code above is that you are doing things in the wrong order. First you check the length of the string and then you input the string. It should be the other way around.

Comment: You need to read the string BEFORE checking its size.   You're doing the reverse.   Compilers take you literally - they won't read your mind, and correct your code for you if you do things in the opposite order you intend.

Comment: I have slight suspicion you don't see the error because you clear the screen immediately after you output it on screen

Answer (score 1):

There are many choices here, but the fundamental use cases are:

1. Read characters until termination condition or limit reached
2. Read until a terminating condition, then truncate
3. Implement specific character processing.

In all of these use cases, you'll need to determine whether to accept white space or skip it.

For all following examples, assume the terminating condition is a line ending (a.k.a. Enter is pressed).

### Read until limit reached

The easiest method here is to use a buffer, the convert to a string:

```
const size_t MAXIMUM_CHARS = 25;
static char buffer[MAXIMUM_CHARS + 1]; // An extra for the terminating nul character.
std::cout << "Enter name";
std::cin.getline(buffer, MAXIMUM_CHARS, '\n');
const std::string name(buffer);
```

### Reading, then truncating

Read in characters, then truncate to the maximum size:

```
const size_t MAXIMUM_CHARS = 25;
std::string name;
std::cout << "Enter name";
std::getline(std::cin, name);
if (name.length() > MAXIMUM_CHARS)
{
  name.erase(MAXIMUM_CHARS);
}
```

### Specific character processing

```
char c;
size_t chars_read;
std::cout << "Enter name";
std::string name;
while (std::cin >> c)
{
  if (valid(c))
  {
    name += c;
  }
  else
  {
    break;
  }
  ++chars_read;
  if (chars_read > MAXIMUM_CHARS)
  {
    break;
  }
}
```

### Summary

Reading and limiting by quantity is possible.  There are different methods to achieve this, as long as you determine the terminating condition and the limit.  Some techniques, which I didn't post involve obtaining key press information from the Operating System and writing your own keyboard (input stream) drivers.  The choice is yours.

Answer (score -1):

You should check the size *after* the name has been input and ask again if it is too long. That would be something like

```
std::string first_name;
for (;;)
{
    cout << "Please enter your name ";
    cin >> first_name;
    if (first_name.size() <= 25)
        break;
    cout << "You must only put 25 characters\n";
}
```

Comment: _"There's no way in C++ to limit the number of characters input before they have been input .."_ Of course there are ways to restrict this at time of input using an I/O manipulator or such. Question is, if it's worth to do those efforts beforehand vs. checking afterwards.

Comment: IMO it's not worth the efforts writing that code. You can of course catch up every single char from input and just count.

Comment: Well, I'd like to know the technique, because I've never seen such code. Maybe you could give me a link.

Comment: OK, I think we're talking at cross purposes, and I think it's not what the OP is asking for in any case. I'll try and clarify my answer.

Comment: If you want to limit the quantity of characters, see `std::getline` or `std::istream::read`.  Both have overloads where you can specify the maximum characters read.

Comment: Another alternative is to read one character at a time, until the termination condition is reached or the maximum quantity is reached.

Comment: Also, the `cin >> string` will terminate after whitespace.  The `std::getline` will read whitespace.  There are i/o manipulators that allow reading of white space (no skipping white space).

Comment: You can limit the number of characters read of course. I said there is no way to limit the number of characters input, which is quite a different thing. You can't stop the characters being typed appearing in the input stream. I thought maybe that was what the OP wanted because of his peculiar code, but I was probably mistaken.